# Add timezone offset to a localized timezone

Tags: ubuntu, centos, date

I am trying to obtain a date string corresponding to "yesterday" (to be understood as 1 day ago) in both a Ubuntu 20.04 and a CentOS 7. I have been successful up to now by using a non-existing timezone such as `aaa`, and applying a 24 hours offset. That is, the command I am trying to execute looks like this:

```bsh
YESTERDAY=`TZ=aaa24 date '+%y%m%d'`
```

This is all good and well, until I realized that the date is not correct for my timezone.
I tried to apply the correct timezone (which, for me, is Europe/Rome), and it stopped working correctly. More precisely:

```bsh
TZ="Europe/Rome" date "+%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z"
20210208 08:25 CET
TZ="Europe/Rome24" date "+%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z"
20210208 07:25 Europe
```

The timezone exposed in the last command sound as like it did not understand correctly the timezone, or it used a default "Europe" timezone that seems synchronized with GMT, all the while ignoring the offset.

I tried to remove the "sub-zone" `/Rome` to make some tries, and it seems that in this case the timezone offset is correctly understood:

```
TZ="Europe" date "+%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z"
20210208 07:25 Europe
TZ="Europe24" date "+%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z"
20210207 07:25 Europe
```

Is there any way to apply the offset to a specific, "sub"-timezone such as Europe/Rome?
Thanks.

Comment: When doing date arithmetic, best to define "yesterday" as "1 day ago", not "24 hours ago" -- for days with 23 hours, "now - 24 hours" might show a date _two days ago_.

Comment: Absolutely right. I shall amend the question! My thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu and CentOS are both using GNU date, so use the `-d` option:

```bsh
 $ date "+%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z"
20210209 10:09 EST

$ date -d "yesterday" "+%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z"
20210208 10:09 EST
```

For more details about how `date` parses the `-d` argument, read "Date input formats" in `info date` (or [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html))

---

Just a reminder that time is weird, especially with daylight saving time: in Cuba, the DST transition happens at midnight, this year (2021) on March 14. [Midnight on that day does not exist](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/cuba/havana):

```bsh
$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-14'
date: invalid date ‘2021-03-14’

# but
$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-14 01:00:00'
Sun Mar 14 01:00:00 CDT 2021
```

And doing date arithmetic in units of days can be different than in units of hours: let's go to March 15 and then step backwards in time:

```bsh
$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-15' '+%Y-%m-%d'
2021-03-15

$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-15 -1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d'
2021-03-14

$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-15 -24 hours' '+%Y-%m-%d'
2021-03-13
```

Why is that? Because March 14, 2021 in Cuba has 23 hours, so subtracting 24 hours goes back 1 day and 1 hour:

```bsh
$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-15' '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2021-03-15 00:00:00

$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-15 -1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2021-03-14 01:00:00

$ env TZ=America/Havana date -d '2021-03-15 -24 hours' '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2021-03-13 23:00:00
```

This is not just restricted to Cuba: any timezone with DST will do that on the day the clock moves forward.

Comment: To those about to tell me "You don't need `env` there", my shell is fish so yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how to accomplish this with the time zone, but the date 24 hours ago can be shown as follows:

```
date -d @$(($(date +%s)-24*3600))
```

This expresses the current date as seconds since 1970 `date +%s`, then subtracts 24 hours. `date -d` displays not the current date, but the date defined by the string that follows.

Comment: Not every day has 86400 seconds.

Comment: The original question defines "yesterday" as "the day that was valid 24 hours ago". Having said that, your answer is better.

Comment: That definition is a problem. See my update